# Sorry-Cypress : minimum setup to run a director and a dashboard in the cloud (InMemory)

Tags: sorrycypress

Starting with Sorry-Cypress.

I'm wondering the basic setup to run in the cloud the docker versions without persistency (MongoDB) but with a Director and a Dashboard.

Ideally it's behind nginx with an already set https.